# `container:init` is not a heroku command

Tags: heroku, docker, heroku-toolbelt

I have installed heroku with homebrew in my OSX El Capitan(10.11.5) and installed the heroku-container-tools with:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-container-tools
```

The installation goes successfully:

```
Installing plugin heroku-container-tools... done
```

When I run a heroku version, I got this:

```
heroku-toolbelt/3.42.22 (universal.x86_64-darwin15) ruby/2.0.0
heroku-cli/5.2.20-9d094b0 (darwin-amd64) go1.6.2
=== Installed Plugins
heroku-container-tools@3.0.0
```

But when I run a heroku container:init I got this:

```
!    `container:init` is not a heroku command.
!    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

Running heroku help container I got this:

```
Usage: heroku container

Use Docker to build and deploy Heroku apps

Use Docker to build and deploy Heroku apps

Additional commands, type "heroku help COMMAND" for more details:

  container:login           #  Logs in to the Heroku Docker registry
  container:push [PROCESS]  #  Builds, then pushes a Docker image to deploy your Heroku app
```

I am following this heroku tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-development-with-docker

In the tutorial is said to run heroku container:init

This command was replaced but some other and heroku did not updated their documentation or I have some problem installing the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they restricted access to their container registry, just read the warning on top of the tutorial you're following https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-development-with-docker

> heroku container:release, which creates a Heroku-compatible slug and
>   deploys it to Heroku, has been deprecated. For access to our container
>   registry (available in private beta), please contact
>   docker-feedback@heroku.com

now there are only `login` and `push` commands. I hope you can easily ask for the access.

Comment: But how can I create the dockerfile? Heroku don't do it anymore?

Comment: yeah, I don't see any other commands in their github repo. You may ask them or create the file manually, just browser their images https://hub.docker.com/u/heroku/, there are plenty of dockerfiles, this is actually what they advise us in the tutorial.